# How to get maximum frame size of each function compiled by gcc?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, stack

Is it possible to get maximum frame size of each function compiled by GCC?

I have a bunch of C and C++ source files in my project and I want to have a statistics of stack usage of each function, just couldn't find any related options in GCC manual.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try `-fstack-usage`.

- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Static-Stack-Usage-Analysis.html

There is also `-Wstack-usage=<stack_limit>` (eg. `-Wstack-usage=4096`) which will give you a warning as you compile your code.

Comment: This is exactly what I want, I'll switch from GCC 4.1.2 to GCC 4.6, thanks mizo :)